# Why does X-D=-490 in the Google calculator?

Tags: calculator

When I type X-D into Google, I come up with -490 as the answer. Anyone know why that happened?

X and D in X-D needs to be capitalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that this is Google handling roman numerals. X=10, D=500.

So X -D = 10 -500 = -490